# Evaluate $\Gamma(-\frac{1}{2})$ directly from the definition of $\Gamma()$

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Can you evaluate $\space\Gamma(-\frac{1}{2})$ directly from the definition $\Gamma(s) = \int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{s-1}dt, $

not using $\space \Gamma(\frac{1}{2}) = \sqrt{\pi}$ and $\Gamma(s+1) = s\Gamma(s)$?

I failed to do the integral just like the way to find $\space \Gamma(\frac{1}{2})$ using polar coordiates, but it looks like it goes to infinity.

Comment: The integral is not convergent, and $\Gamma$ is defined beyond the plane ${\rm Re } z>0$ only by analytic continuation.

Comment: That integral definition is valid only if $\mathrm{Re} (s)>0$. In particular, the integral is divergent for $s=-1/2$.

Comment: Thank both of you for quick answers. I missed out the condition. Then, how can we plot the Gamma function where Re(s) < 0, even roughly? (I saw the plot in the left plane where poles are at all negtive integers) Is there another def. or representation of the function including Re(s) < 0 ?

Comment: @DavidLee Yes, read through https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Definition

Comment: Integration by parts show that  $\int_{0}^{\infty} \left(e^{-x}-1 \right)x^{s-1} \, \mathrm dx = \frac{\Gamma(s+1)}{s} = \Gamma(s)$ for $- 1 < \Re(s) < 0$.

Comment: @Random Variable  / Thank you. I understand $Re(s)\lt0$. Why $Re(s)\gt-1$??

Comment: The integrand behaves like $-x^{s}$ as $x \to 0^{+}$.

Answer (score 1):

If we put $s=-\frac12$ in the definition, we get
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}{t^{3/2}}dt>\int_0^1\frac{e^{-t}}{t^{3/2}}dt>\int_0^1\frac{e^{-1}}{t^{3/2}}dt=\lim_{\delta\to  0^+}\frac{2}{e}(\frac{1}{\sqrt\delta}-1)=\infty.$$
So, the improper integral is divergent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.